# Django: set timezone in admin?

Tags: django, timezone, django-admin

I'm developing a system to be used in an intranet setting in different locations. This means each setup of the system will have its own database, and I want to be able to set the timezone on a system level. I can change the timezone manually for each in `settings.py`, but this is far from ideal. I could set the timezone on a per-user basis by adding a timezone field to a user profile, but this would also require a correct default timezone which would have to be set somewhere.

So, my goal: a system-wide timezone that can be set by the administrator through the admin interface. Is there a good way to do this? My first thought was to create a model just for this and somehow limit it to only having one instance in the database, but this doesn't seem very elegant.

Answer (score -1):

Without having implemented what you are describing, I think the docs give a pretty good overview of how to do what you want. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone

Comment: Evergreen link to latest stable docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone

Answer (score -2):

In settings.py

```
USE_L10N = True
```

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#use-l10n) says

> USE_L10N
>
> Default: False
>
> A boolean that specifies if localized formatting of data will be
>   enabled by default or not. If this is set to True, e.g. Django will
>   display numbers and dates using the format of the current locale.
>
> See also LANGUAGE_CODE, USE_I18N and USE_TZ.

And [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#date-format)

> DATE_FORMAT
>
> Default: 'N j, Y' (e.g. Feb. 4, 2003)
>
> The default formatting to use for displaying date fields in any part
>   of the system. Note that if USE_L10N is set to True, then the
>   locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied
>   instead. See allowed date format strings.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the displayed formatting of the date/time. I'm trying to change the timezone itself.

Comment: `USE_TZ` has to do with whether the datetimes are naive or use the specified timezone, not setting/selecting the timezone.